# Amazon OpenSearch Service upgrade to from 2.3 to 2.5 hangs at 50% since 2 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-opensearch

I tried to upgrade our production Amazon OpenSearch Service from 2.3 to 2.5 (after making the check which said OK) but the upgrade hangs since 16. March (two days) at 50% and now (at 6:00 ) the Snapshot failure status went from green to red.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this with basic support plan? Or do I need to burn $100 for a business support plan?

Comment: do you have access to error logs in the opensearch dashboard / cloudwatch?

Comment: no they were disabled

Comment: you could repeat the operation with the logs enabled (best practice when you're doing business critical ops). Also, you can submit a request to AWS free of charge also with the basic support plan

Comment: Repeating the operation is not possible: it shows "Performing engine upgrade. Domain status will become Active once upgrade is completed." and I can't trigger a new upgrade.
And submitting a request free of charge is not possible as far as I've seen - I had to upgrade to the Developer Support plan.